# Very odd and slow backup restore

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I have an older Dell Latitude XT Tablet that the 120GB drive fails smart, so I backed it up 3 or 4 different ways to a 1.5TB USB with 3 primary partitions.

1. cloned to the 2nd primary by easeus usb flash boot
2. Macrium Image (no compression, not intelligent copy)
3. Seagate Free (by Acronis) Image
4. Data rescue dd.

I purchased an identical new drive, smart reports good, etc. Replaced it and tried to restore to it from a boot cd MiniXP (Hiren's)

All the backups took between 1 - 3 hrs to do (the cloning obviously sector by sector took the longest) but I've tried to restore 4 or 5 different ways, even an attempted partition copy operation using Partition Wizard and it seems that it's gonna take about 20 hours to do via Macrium and Rawcopy reports 66 hours.

Any ideas? I am using the same zif cable, just swapped the old drive for a new one.

Starting to drive me nuts so I terminated Macrium after 11 hours at only 60% complete. Also terminated the other restore attempts or partition copy attempts when I realized this was taking much longer than I figured it should.

BTW didn't set the restores to verify anything, just restore.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Restore the partitions one at a time, starting with the first partition and ending with the last, use acronis to do this.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the question.  This a USB 2.0 or 3.0 external drive?

Comment: It is a USB 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I am only restoring one partition, C, from a clone residing on the 2nd of 3 partitions on a 1.5TB usb 2.0 drive. I finally used Rawcopy (by Roadkill) , it took about 20 hours. After the copy, C drive is now seen by Explorer, Disk Management and a few other drive and partition utilities running from a MiniXP environment as unformatted. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhW9V.jpg The ONLY tool that sees it as it should is Minitool's Partition Wizard. I can explore the drive filesystem with *its* built in Explorer. https://i.stack.imgur.com/edCEB.jpg Incidentally it's the tool I originally used to manipulate the USB drive's partitions (move unallocated space around after initially cloning my old C drive to one of the 3 primary partitions on the USB). I burned a Minitool Partition Wizard boot disk and will see if it can fix why Windows does not see the restored C partition as a legit formatted drive, complete with filesystem. DiskGenius reports an error:the number of sectors record in DBR overflow and has a "correct"  action button so it appears to be an easy fix but we shall see, I'll try that.

Comment: Hi Jay, this looks as if it should have been an edit on your answer?

Comment: Sorry @bummi, a little confused how to update my thread. Update, Disk Genius fixed it, http://imgur.com/nUp5vn8 guess it was just a partition table error. Drive C: is now seen by Windows MiniXP. I can finally shutdown and see if it will boot off the new internal drive restored from a copy. Ramhound my question was if it was typical for data transfer from external USB 2.0 to a laptop drive be 1/5 the speed of internal drive transfers out to external USB2?

Comment: If your are question is answered by your answer anything should be fine, maybe I've just problems to understand. I was under the impression the desired target state is not reached, in this case it should have been an edit on the question.